# Jnlp can be launched from Cygwin but not MS-DOS using javaws

Tags: java, windows

I can launch a JNLP file from Cygwin but not MS-DOS on the same machine. I am using javaws and getting the error to the effect that javaw.exe not found. I read http://javatechniques.com/blog/launching-java-webstart-from-the-command-line/. that one can use java compiler to do the launch  So I tried that as well that looks something like this:

```
 c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin>java -classpath 
"C:\Program     Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\javaws.jar; 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\deploy.jar"   
-Djnlpx.home="C:Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin"   
-Djnlpx.jvm="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin\javaw.exe"   
-Djnlpx.remove=true 
-Djnlpx.splashport=-1  
 com.sun.javaws.Main c:\tmp2\new_3.jnlp
```

And when I do that I get this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/deploy/util/DeploySysRun
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544) 
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.deploy.util.DeploySysRun
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thanking you

Comment: There is no Java for MS-DOS, so it's not a surprise you cannot launch a JNLP file from there. Or are actually talking about the command line in Windows?

Comment: Type `set Path` in a command window.  If none of those directories are the bin directory of a Java installation, you must either modify the Path environment variable, or refer to javaws.exe by its full path.

Comment: I was able to resolve by using power shell. Hope this helps someone.